# Can you return a result back to Flutter from Native Kotlin Bridge

Tags: flutter, kotlin, bridge

at the moment I have a Flutter App that when I press a button it opens a Native Kotlin activity(mainActivity), once this executes I automatically open a SecondActivity that extends AppCompatActivity, the issue becomes is that I want to return a bool from the SecondActivity back to Flutter.

At the moment when the process finishes i use "finish()" to close my Native code and return to flutter successfully but I'd like to pass a result to Flutter.

I know how to do it from the mainActivity as it uses the FlutterActivity directly and can pass "result.success()", but from the different activity I can't find a solution.

I was wondering if somebody can tell me how to pass the bool from the secondActivity to Flutter.

Thank you very much everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly the same. Store [Result](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.Result.html) in class property and call one of its methods from [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) when the second activity finishes. Something like this:

```
class YourPlugin ... {
...
  private var pendingResult: Result? = null
...

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
...
    pendingResult = result
    activity?.startActivityForResult(...)
...
  }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Boolean {
...
    pendingResult?.success(<result>)
...
    return false
  }
```

Comment: It's not too clear to me at the moment as I'm very new to Kotlin, but I think I know where you're, if possible you could give me a slight example It would be really apreciated, thanks!

Comment: Wow!! Real nice Example Thank you so much!